# How to evaluate the determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix in a shortcut method?

Tags: matrices, determinant

How to evaluate the determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix? I want to know the shortcut method.
For e.g.$-$ If A $=$ $$\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 7 \\
2 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ , then the value of $|A|$ is $|A|=6$.
Again if B $=$ $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 3 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$.
Here clearly $|B|$=$$2\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 6 \\
5 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ $-$ $$3\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 \\
3 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$ $+$ $$4\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
3 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$. Therefore the value of $|B|=2$.
Similarly in this way we can also find the determinants of a $4 \times 4$ matrix, $5 \times 5$ matrix, etc. But if we clearly notice one thing then we can clearly see that it will be a very much lengthy process to find the determinants of a $n \times n$ matrix(for $n\geq 4$). For this reason only I want to know that is there any shortcut method for finding the determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix ?

Comment: Short answer: No, there is no shortcut. Finding a determinant is quite a lengthy process to do by hand. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81529/computational-complexity-of-computing-the-determinant

Comment: For an $n \times n$ matrix ,  the best way to find its determinant is to reduce the matrix to row echelon form, and then multiply the diagonal elements, times the sign changes resulting from exchanging rows along the way, as well as the row scale factors.

Comment: Ok. I have understood @HosamH